# Why does my site look different on Firefox vs every other browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am just playing around with a site and I noticed that while my site looks good on Chrome, Safari and others. It doesn't flow the same on Firefox(23). How does Firefox handle things like padding and height?

Chrome:

[image: Here it is on Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Here is my CSS:

```
    /*----------all small sizes------------*/
a.small-block{
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 134px;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin: 2.5%;
}
a.about{
    background-color: #CBA70C;
}
a.music{
    background-color: #F35C4D;

}
a.pictures {
    background-color: #6398FF;
}
a.feedback {
    background-color: #B82808;
}
/*----------end of small boxes---------*/

/*------------medium boxes--------------*/
a.med-block{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin: 2.5%;
}
a.albums {
    background-color: #B34945;
}
a.songs {
    background-color: #80ADEA;
}
/*------------end of medium boxes---------*/

/*--------------big box--------------*/
a.big-block{
    font-size: 1.875em;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 187px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 160px 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top:2.5%;
}
a.history{
    background-color: #A3BF3B;    
}
/*-------------end of big box-----------------*/

a.med-block, a.small-block, a.big-block {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 250ms ease-out 0s;
}
```

It looks to me as Firefox is reading the padding differently. If I change it up to look well on Firefox every other browser looks different

Comment: A link to your site would be useful if it's external accessible.

Comment: It's not. I provided the (what I thought) relevant code. If you need to see more just let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `box-sizing: border-box;` for the other browsers - you only have the `-moz` prefix defined for the below selectors:

```
a.med-block, a.small-block, a.big-block {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 250ms ease-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: well I ended up just removing it. That seemed to make it work properly on ff.

Answer (score -2):

Try this it will only style your item in firefox. so you add additional code for firefox.

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
    color: red;
    }
}
```